# How to correct dynamic stability of UAV fuselages?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, wing, flight-controls

I was trying to design a fuselage model of UAV with considering lift coefficient (CL), after this I analyzed stability of both wing on fuselage. First I did the individual analysis for wing and fuselage in which the result of main wing analysis is quite good but after adding fuselage the dynamic stability of the UAV was not perfect.

If any information might be lacking I would love to add details and I am onto sure if my question is reliable for this forum ,if so it would be great if you could suggest a specified forums where I can discuss with this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which stability derivative are you seeking correction?

Comment: Overal dynamic stability in turning and banking.

Comment: I don't understand. Dynamic stability (rigid-body) refers to phugoid, SP, dutch-roll, etc., which are affected by their respective stability derivatives, and drag (only for phugoid). Turning and banking aren't typically associated with dynamic stability since they are maneuvers.

Comment: I got that point that’s why I was so confused about the factors that affect the dynamic stability of fixed wing plane and I will try to reconsider whole analysis with your point of view. If you are comfortable It would be great to talk to you in details.

Comment: You need to present some data here in order for people to help you. What are you analyzing exactly? What are you comparing, and against what? What exactly is inconsistent, and against what? As the OP stands, I don't even know what your issues are.

Comment: If it would help, consider turning and banking as unstable conditions.  You want your plane stable on 3 axes with no control input, but *unstable* when a control input is added.  Otherwise, you cannot pitch, yaw, or roll.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr.DiGiovanni. I got my answer.